# Get two more values from Javascript object. it is possible?

Tags: javascript, object

My object is

```
objTest["CT_1^PS_1^OP01"] = "test1";
objTest["CT_1^PS_1^OP02"] = "test2";
objTest["CT_1^PS_1^OP03"] = "test3";
```

and My stirng is

```
string sFindVal = "CT_1^PS_1";
```

Is it possible to bring the "value" of the word beginning with "CT_1^PS_1"?

I want to get values ("test1", "test2", "test3")  only key is "CT_1^PS_1".

English is not my mother tongue.
Please understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to return an array of all the values where the key [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the string

```js
const objTest = {};

objTest["CT_1\\PS_1\\OP01"] = "test1";
objTest["CP_1\\PS_1\\OP01"] = "error";
objTest["CT_1\\PS_1\\OP02"] = "test2";
objTest["CT_1\\PS_1\\OP03"] = "test3";

const sFindVal = "CT_1\\PS_1";

const arr = Object.keys(objTest).reduce((arr, key) => {
  if (key.includes(sFindVal)) arr.push(objTest[key]);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```